# How do I save a input key into a variable in assembly

Tags: assembly, keyboard, x86

I'm using an x86 arquitecture on 8086 intel. I want to save the keys user's strikes into a variable so I can use that information later. The problem I'm getting is that I'm saving something but not the keys I'm stroking. Im using a keymap already so that's not the problem. Here is what I programmed in the keyboard interruption method:

```
 keyboard: 
         cli
                in al,60h       
                cmp al,1Ch       ;Enter 
                jne @f           
                 mov [started],1
                 call paintScreenBlack
                 jmp final
                @@:             ;Procedure for saving the key
                cmp al,128
                ja final          ;it checks if its a valid key 
                 cmp [started],1 
                 je final
                   xor ebx,ebx
                   mov bl,al
                   mov cl,[keymap+ebx] ;I save in cl the character according to the key
                   xor eax,eax   
                   mov al,[word] ; Word is the variable where I want to save the information
                   mov bx,[cont] ; I check how many characters the user has striked
                   mov [eax+ebx],cl ;I  save the character into the corresponding position
                   inc [cont] ; I count another character
                   call dibcar  ;Then I do something else
         final: mov al,20h                  ;end of hardware interruption
                out     20h,al                  ; to master pic
                sti
                iret
```

I'm using Text mode with a screen resolution of 50x80

Comment: Why is `word` a single byte? Also, you forgot to provide [MCVE]. As always, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I'm afraid that's impossible with assembly, I will have to upload my whole code. Does it matters word is a single byte

Comment: You use it as an address which is very suspicious. You also forgot to mention what mode you are in.

Comment: I'm using text mode. What can I do to fix that?, please is really important

Comment: I meant, real mode or protected mode. You also don't show how `word` is initialized and how your buffer is declared/allocated.

Comment: protected mode and  (word db ' ') and about the buffer I don't know what do you mean I'm kind of new in this language